# e4x: how to best check existence of an attribute?

Tags: javascript, e4x

I know I can do it with the length() method:

```
>x = <a attr1='33' />
>x.@attr1
33
>x.@attr1.length()
1
>x.@attr2.length()
0
```

so I could use

```
if (x.@someattr.length() > 0)
{
    .... do something ....
}
```

but is there a more appropriate way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I found the answer by poring through the [Ecma-357 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-357.htm), particularly the XML.prototype.* and XMLList.prototype.* sections 13.4 and 13.5.

It's the `hasOwnProperty()` method:

```
js>x = <a attr1='33' ><item>gumball!</item></a>
<a attr1="33">
  <item>gumball!</item>
</a>
js>x.@attr1
33
js>x.hasOwnProperty('@attr1');
true
js>x.hasOwnProperty('@attr2');
false
js>x.hasOwnProperty('item');
true
js>x.hasOwnProperty('mongoose');
false
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest way:

```
(@attr1 in theXML)
```

this will return true if id attrtibute exists and false otherwise.